# Why each node owns 100.0%?

Tags: cassandra

I have started nodes of cassandra via:

```
/usr/sbin/cassandra -f
```

But, I've noticed that each node owns 100.0% of cluster! shouldn't each node get its share of ownership? ex: 33.33% ?

[image]

Comment: What consistency and keyspace replication factor level are you using ?

Comment: I didn't set it, how would I check?

Comment: I tried to run cqlsh, but I got error: `cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})`

Comment: The replication factor is set on keyspace definition (CREATE KEYSPACE statement) or you can run `SELECT * FROM system.schema_keyspaces;`. Consistency level is specified at query level with `USING CONSISTENCY` clause. If you want to know your default consistency run the command `CONSISTENCY` in `cqlsh`.

Comment: Have you put some data into this cluster? Have you flushed memtables?

Comment: Most likely your `RF = N (3)`. Your replication factor is equal to number of nodes. So every piece of data will exist on all nodes.